# Tensorflow Lite error Unity : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tensorflow-lite

I have a tflite model that takes image as input and predict its class label. but when I am using this code,there is an error like this

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
> TensorFlowLite.Interpreter..ctor (System.Byte[] modelData, TensorFlowLite.InterpreterOptions options) (at ./Packages/com.github.asus4.tflite/Runtime/Interpreter.cs:71)
> TensorFlowLite.Interpreter..ctor (System.Byte[] modelData) (at ./Packages/com.github.asus4.tflite/Runtime/Interpreter.cs:60)
> ImageClassifier.LoadModelAndLabels (System.String modelPath, System.String labelPath) (at Assets/Samples/Detection/Scripts/PythonBridge.cs:58)
> ImageClassifier.Start () (at Assets/Samples/Detection/Scripts/PythonBridge.cs:28)

I have used tensorflow lite from here [Github](https://github.com/asus4/tf-lite-unity-sample)

this is my program code .cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using TensorFlowLite;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

public class ImageClassifier : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Serialized fields to set from the Unity Editor
    [SerializeField] private string modelFileName = "project.tflite";
    [SerializeField] private string labelFileName = "class_labels.txt";
    [SerializeField] private Texture2D inputImage;

    private Interpreter interpreter;
    private string[] labels;
    private float[] imgData; // Flatten the image data array
    private float[,] output;

 void Start()
{
    string modelPath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, modelFileName);
    string labelPath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, labelFileName);

    Debug.Log("Model path: " + modelPath);
    Debug.Log("Label path: " + labelPath);

    if (!LoadModelAndLabels(modelPath, labelPath))
    {
        Debug.LogError("Failed to load model and labels.");
        return;
    }

    // Load image from previous scene and preprocess it
    string imagePath = DisplayCapturedImage.imagePath;
    Debug.Log("Image path: " + imagePath);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imagePath))
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadImageAndRunInference(imagePath));
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Image path is not set or is empty.");
    }
}

private bool LoadModelAndLabels(string modelPath, string labelPath)
{
    Debug.Log("Loading model from path: " + modelPath);
    if (File.Exists(modelPath))
    {
        byte[] modelData = File.ReadAllBytes(modelPath);
        if (modelData == null || modelData.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Model data is null or empty");
            return false;
        }
        interpreter = new Interpreter(modelData);
        interpreter.AllocateTensors();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Model file not found at " + modelPath);
        return false;
    }

    Debug.Log("Loading labels from path: " + labelPath);
    if (File.Exists(labelPath))
    {
        labels = File.ReadAllLines(labelPath)
            .Select(s => s.Trim())
            .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            .ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError("Label file not found at " + labelPath);
        return false;
    }

    Debug.Log("Model and labels loaded successfully");
    int outputCount = interpreter.GetOutputTensorInfo(0).shape[1];
    output = new float[1, outputCount];
    return true;
}

    IEnumerator LoadImageAndRunInference(string imagePath)
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture("file://" + imagePath);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.LogError(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Texture2D texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
            PreprocessImage(texture);
            RunInference();
        }
    }
void PreprocessImage(Texture2D image)
{
    // Resize image to the model input size
    Texture2D resizedImage = Resize(image, 224, 224);

    int height = resizedImage.height;
    int width = resizedImage.width;
    int channels = 3; // Assuming the model expects a 3-channel RGB image

    imgData = new float[height * width * channels]; // Flatten the image data array

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            Color color = resizedImage.GetPixel(x, y);

            // Normalize pixel values to [0, 1] if needed
            int i = (y * width + x) * channels;
            imgData[i + 0] = color.r;
            imgData[i + 1] = color.g;
            imgData[i + 2] = color.b;
        }
    }

    // Dispose of the resized image to free up memory
    Destroy(resizedImage);
}

Texture2D Resize(Texture2D source, int newWidth, int newHeight)

{
source.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;
RenderTexture rt = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(newWidth, newHeight);
rt.filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;
RenderTexture.active = rt;
Graphics.Blit(source, rt);
Texture2D result = new Texture2D(newWidth, newHeight);
result.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight), 0, 0);
result.Apply();
RenderTexture.active = null;
RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(rt);
return result;
}


void RunInference()
{
    interpreter.SetInputTensorData(0, imgData);
    interpreter.Invoke();

    float[] outputData = new float[output.GetLength(1)]; // Flatten the output array
    interpreter.GetOutputTensorData(0, outputData);

    int predictedIndex = GetPredictedIndex(outputData);
    string predictedLabel = labels[predictedIndex];
    Debug.Log($"Predicted class: {predictedLabel}");
}

int GetPredictedIndex(float[] probabilities)
{
   int predictedIndex = 0;
float maxProbability = probabilities[0];

for (int i = 1; i < probabilities.Length; i++)
{
    if (probabilities[i] > maxProbability)
    {
        maxProbability = probabilities[i];
        predictedIndex = i;
    }
}

return predictedIndex;
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    if (interpreter != null)
    {
        interpreter.Dispose();
        interpreter = null;
    }
}

}
```

this is interpreter.cs which is giving error

```
/* Copyright 2018 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
==============================================================================*/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe;
using TfLiteInterpreter = System.IntPtr;
using TfLiteInterpreterOptions = System.IntPtr;
using TfLiteModel = System.IntPtr;
using TfLiteTensor = System.IntPtr;

namespace TensorFlowLite
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Simple C# bindings for the experimental TensorFlowLite C API.
    /// </summary>
    public class Interpreter : IDisposable
    {
        public struct TensorInfo
        {
            public string name { get; internal set; }
            public DataType type { get; internal set; }
            public int[] shape { get; internal set; }
            public QuantizationParams quantizationParams { get; internal set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("name: {0}, type: {1}, dimensions: {2}, quantizationParams: {3}",
                  name,
                  type,
                  "[" + string.Join(",", shape) + "]",
                  "{" + quantizationParams + "}");
            }
        }

        private TfLiteModel model = IntPtr.Zero;
        private TfLiteInterpreter interpreter = IntPtr.Zero;
        private readonly InterpreterOptions options = null;
        private readonly GCHandle modelDataHandle;
        private readonly Dictionary<int, GCHandle> inputDataHandles = new Dictionary<int, GCHandle>();
        private readonly Dictionary<int, GCHandle> outputDataHandles = new Dictionary<int, GCHandle>();


        internal TfLiteInterpreter InterpreterPointer => interpreter;

        public Interpreter(byte[] modelData) : this(modelData, null) { }

        public Interpreter(byte[] modelData, InterpreterOptions options)
        {
            modelDataHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(modelData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            IntPtr modelDataPtr = modelDataHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            model = TfLiteModelCreate(modelDataPtr, modelData.Length);
            if (model == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Exception("Failed to create TensorFlowLite Model");

            this.options = options ?? new InterpreterOptions();

            interpreter = TfLiteInterpreterCreate(model, options.nativePtr);
            if (interpreter == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Exception("Failed to create TensorFlowLite Interpreter");
        }


        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            if (interpreter != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                TfLiteInterpreterDelete(interpreter);
                interpreter = IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            if (model != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                TfLiteModelDelete(model);
                model = IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            options?.Dispose();

            foreach (var handle in inputDataHandles.Values)
            {
                handle.Free();
            }
            foreach (var handle in outputDataHandles.Values)
            {
                handle.Free();
            }
            modelDataHandle.Free();
        }

        public virtual void Invoke()
        {
            ThrowIfError(TfLiteInterpreterInvoke(interpreter));
        }

        public int GetInputTensorCount()
        {
            return TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensorCount(interpreter);
        }

        public void SetInputTensorData(int inputTensorIndex, Array inputTensorData)
        {
            if (!inputDataHandles.TryGetValue(inputTensorIndex, out GCHandle tensorDataHandle))
            {
                tensorDataHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(inputTensorData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                inputDataHandles.Add(inputTensorIndex, tensorDataHandle);
            }
            IntPtr tensorDataPtr = tensorDataHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            TfLiteTensor tensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensor(interpreter, inputTensorIndex);
            ThrowIfError(TfLiteTensorCopyFromBuffer(tensor, tensorDataPtr, Buffer.ByteLength(inputTensorData)));
        }

        public unsafe void SetInputTensorData<T>(int inputTensorIndex, in ReadOnlySpan<T> inputTensorData)
            where T : unmanaged
        {
            fixed (T* dataPtr = inputTensorData)
            {
                IntPtr tensorDataPtr = (IntPtr)dataPtr;
                TfLiteTensor tensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensor(interpreter, inputTensorIndex);
                ThrowIfError(TfLiteTensorCopyFromBuffer(
                    tensor, tensorDataPtr, inputTensorData.Length * UnsafeUtility.SizeOf<T>()));
            }
        }

        public unsafe void SetInputTensorData<T>(int inputTensorIndex, in NativeArray<T> inputTensorData)
            where T : unmanaged
        {
            IntPtr tensorDataPtr = (IntPtr)NativeArrayUnsafeUtility.GetUnsafePtr(inputTensorData);
            TfLiteTensor tensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensor(interpreter, inputTensorIndex);
            ThrowIfError(TfLiteTensorCopyFromBuffer(
                tensor, tensorDataPtr, inputTensorData.Length * UnsafeUtility.SizeOf<T>()));
        }

        public void ResizeInputTensor(int inputTensorIndex, int[] inputTensorShape)
        {
            ThrowIfError(TfLiteInterpreterResizeInputTensor(
                interpreter, inputTensorIndex, inputTensorShape, inputTensorShape.Length));
        }

        public void AllocateTensors()
        {
            ThrowIfError(TfLiteInterpreterAllocateTensors(interpreter));
        }

        public int GetOutputTensorCount()
        {
            return TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensorCount(interpreter);
        }

        public void GetOutputTensorData(int outputTensorIndex, Array outputTensorData)
        {
            if (!outputDataHandles.TryGetValue(outputTensorIndex, out GCHandle tensorDataHandle))
            {
                tensorDataHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(outputTensorData, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                outputDataHandles.Add(outputTensorIndex, tensorDataHandle);
            }
            IntPtr tensorDataPtr = tensorDataHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            TfLiteTensor tensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor(interpreter, outputTensorIndex);
            ThrowIfError(TfLiteTensorCopyToBuffer(tensor, tensorDataPtr, Buffer.ByteLength(outputTensorData)));
        }

        public unsafe void GetOutputTensorData<T>(int outputTensorIndex, in Span<T> outputTensorData)
            where T : unmanaged
        {
            fixed (T* dataPtr = outputTensorData)
            {
                IntPtr tensorDataPtr = (IntPtr)dataPtr;
                TfLiteTensor tensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor(interpreter, outputTensorIndex);
                ThrowIfError(TfLiteTensorCopyToBuffer(
                    tensor, tensorDataPtr, outputTensorData.Length * UnsafeUtility.SizeOf<T>()));
            }
        }

        public TensorInfo GetInputTensorInfo(int index)
        {
            TfLiteTensor tensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensor(interpreter, index);
            return GetTensorInfo(tensor);
        }

        public TensorInfo GetOutputTensorInfo(int index)
        {
            TfLiteTensor tensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor(interpreter, index);
            return GetTensorInfo(tensor);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a string describing version information of the TensorFlow Lite library.
        /// TensorFlow Lite uses semantic versioning.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A string describing version information</returns>
        public static string GetVersion()
        {
            return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(TfLiteVersion());
        }

        private static string GetTensorName(TfLiteTensor tensor)
        {
            return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(TfLiteTensorName(tensor));
        }

        protected static TensorInfo GetTensorInfo(TfLiteTensor tensor)
        {
            int[] dimensions = new int[TfLiteTensorNumDims(tensor)];
            for (int i = 0; i < dimensions.Length; i++)
            {
                dimensions[i] = TfLiteTensorDim(tensor, i);
            }
            return new TensorInfo()
            {
                name = GetTensorName(tensor),
                type = TfLiteTensorType(tensor),
                shape = dimensions,
                quantizationParams = TfLiteTensorQuantizationParams(tensor),
            };
        }

        protected TfLiteTensor GetInputTensor(int inputTensorIndex)
        {
            return TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensor(interpreter, inputTensorIndex);
        }

        protected TfLiteTensor GetOutputTensor(int outputTensorIndex)
        {
            return TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor(interpreter, outputTensorIndex);
        }

        protected static void ThrowIfError(Status status)
        {
            switch (status)
            {
                case Status.Ok:
                    return;
                case Status.Error:
                    throw new Exception("TensorFlowLite operation failed.");
                case Status.DelegateError:
                    throw new Exception("TensorFlowLite delegate operation failed.");
                case Status.ApplicationError:
                    throw new Exception("Applying TensorFlowLite delegate operation failed.");
                case Status.DelegateDataNotFound:
                    throw new Exception("Serialized delegate data not being found.");
                case Status.DelegateDataWriteError:
                    throw new Exception("Writing data to delegate failed.");
                case Status.DelegateDataReadError:
                    throw new Exception("Reading data from delegate failed.");
                case Status.UnresolvedOps:
                    throw new Exception("Ops not found.");
                default:
                    throw new Exception($"Unknown TensorFlowLite error: {status}");
            }
        }

        #region Externs

#if UNITY_IOS && !UNITY_EDITOR
        internal const string TensorFlowLibrary = "__Internal";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
        internal const string TensorFlowLibrary = "libtensorflowlite_jni";
#else
        internal const string TensorFlowLibrary = "libtensorflowlite_c";
#endif

        // TfLiteStatus
        public enum Status
        {
            Ok = 0,
            Error = 1,
            DelegateError = 2,
            ApplicationError = 3,
            DelegateDataNotFound = 4,
            DelegateDataWriteError = 5,
            DelegateDataReadError = 6,
            UnresolvedOps = 7,
        }

        // TfLiteType
        public enum DataType
        {
            NoType = 0,
            Float32 = 1,
            Int32 = 2,
            UInt8 = 3,
            Int64 = 4,
            String = 5,
            Bool = 6,
            Int16 = 7,
            Complex64 = 8,
            Int8 = 9,
            Float16 = 10,
            Float64 = 11,
            Complex128 = 12,
            UInt64 = 13,
            Resource = 14,
            Variant = 15,
            UInt32 = 16,
            UInt16 = 17,
        }

        public struct QuantizationParams
        {
            public float scale;
            public int zeroPoint;

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format("scale: {0} zeroPoint: {1}", scale, zeroPoint);
            }
        }

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe IntPtr TfLiteVersion();

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe TfLiteInterpreter TfLiteModelCreate(IntPtr model_data, int model_size);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe void TfLiteModelDelete(TfLiteModel model);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe TfLiteInterpreter TfLiteInterpreterCreate(
            TfLiteModel model,
            TfLiteInterpreterOptions optional_options);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe void TfLiteInterpreterDelete(TfLiteInterpreter interpreter);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe int TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensorCount(
            TfLiteInterpreter interpreter);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe TfLiteTensor TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensor(
            TfLiteInterpreter interpreter,
            int input_index);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe Status TfLiteInterpreterResizeInputTensor(
            TfLiteInterpreter interpreter,
            int input_index,
            int[] input_dims,
            int input_dims_size);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe Status TfLiteInterpreterAllocateTensors(
            TfLiteInterpreter interpreter);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe Status TfLiteInterpreterInvoke(TfLiteInterpreter interpreter);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe int TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensorCount(
            TfLiteInterpreter interpreter);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe TfLiteTensor TfLiteInterpreterGetOutputTensor(
            TfLiteInterpreter interpreter,
            int output_index);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe DataType TfLiteTensorType(TfLiteTensor tensor);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe int TfLiteTensorNumDims(TfLiteTensor tensor);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern int TfLiteTensorDim(TfLiteTensor tensor, int dim_index);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern uint TfLiteTensorByteSize(TfLiteTensor tensor);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe IntPtr TfLiteTensorName(TfLiteTensor tensor);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe QuantizationParams TfLiteTensorQuantizationParams(TfLiteTensor tensor);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe Status TfLiteTensorCopyFromBuffer(
            TfLiteTensor tensor,
            IntPtr input_data,
            int input_data_size);

        [DllImport(TensorFlowLibrary)]
        private static extern unsafe Status TfLiteTensorCopyToBuffer(
            TfLiteTensor tensor,
            IntPtr output_data,
            int output_data_size);

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I used some debugs to check the problem. it is printing this:

> Model path: D:/MainProject/github/tf-lite-unity-sample-master/Assets/StreamingAssets\project.tflite
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
> ImageClassifier:Start () (at Assets/Samples/Detection/Scripts/PythonBridge.cs:25)

> Label path: D:/MainProject/github/tf-lite-unity-sample-master/Assets/StreamingAssets\class_labels.txt
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
> ImageClassifier:Start () (at Assets/Samples/Detection/Scripts/PythonBridge.cs:26)

> Loading model from path: D:/MainProject/github/tf-lite-unity-sample-master/Assets/StreamingAssets\project.tflite
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
> ImageClassifier:LoadModelAndLabels (string,string) (at Assets/Samples/Detection/Scripts/PythonBridge.cs:49)
> ImageClassifier:Start () (at Assets/Samples/Detection/Scripts/PythonBridge.cs:28)

But model is not loaded succesfully

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Nope it doesnot

Comment: Rephrase your question then. The answer in my comment helps to fix that exact runtime exception in any scenario. If you did everything there, you should know what your actual problem is and ask for it as the question instead. Presenting a specific question as generic one doesn't help anyone on SO.

Comment: There's no need to be rude to new posters. Their question even included a stack trace with line numbers and debugging messages to help track down the issue. It was sufficiently detailed to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the first constructor here, which simply calls the second constructor with a null options parameter.

```
    public Interpreter(byte[] modelData) : this(modelData, null) { }

    public Interpreter(byte[] modelData, InterpreterOptions options)
```

The following line in the second constructor attempts to access the .nativePtr property of that options object, which is null, and will produce that exception:

```
    interpreter = TfLiteInterpreterCreate(model, options.nativePtr);
```

You will need an actual InterpreterOptions object to make this work since I don't see a version of that function without that parameter.

I can't help you with creating that object, but I hope this helps.